# How to run Python Script in Laravel?

Tags: php, python, laravel

I wanted to know how to run python script using php code. I have tried different options like

```
 $output = exec("python  /var/GAAutomationScript.py");

 $command = escapeshellcmd('/var/GAAutomationScript.py');
 $output = shell_exec($command);
```

But unable to run the python script. My application is in Laravel. Is it possible to run python script using Laravel scheduler jobs e.g. using artisan commands?

Comment: Is the python script executable by the account running the web server?

Comment: This subject is answered very detailed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020068/running-python-script-in-laravel

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Answer (score 3):

Some things to mention about your question :

- I will highly recommend use [`symfony/process`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) instead of shell_exec directly. It is already available in laravel. You can check easily if your command is successful or not and get standard output in string format etc
- When you run a shell script from a web app, the user permissions matter. For example, the laravel web user is `www-data` and your python script is lets say `ubuntu.nbody` for example, it will then check what permissions the python script has. Are users other than `ubuntu` in this example are allowed to run it.
- Then if you think giving 777 permissions to python script will get rid of the permission problem then thats a risk too.
- Last but not the least, create a laravel console command, add the snippet which would run python script from `symfony/process`. Then run it and debug the errors. once it works then you can add that as in laravel's cron jon.

[See this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) to know mo about scheduling artisan commands.

You can also avoid creating artisan command and add shell directly, as it internally uses `symfony/process`. [See this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#scheduling-shell-commands) for that reference

Comment: Hi, I got an error about a module not found when I am trying to import an external extension inside my python code even though the python code is runnable via terminal. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: @Forrest Are you sure that you are using exact same command which works on local in your laravel app? Can you give some more info so it is easy to check the error?

Comment: Hi, my problem is solved. I actually have to import it with an absolute path. Thanks