# Running python script in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, python, laravel

I'm trying to run a python script from laravel. I'm using the version `5.6`.

In a controller I have this

```
public function test_python()
{
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python ' . public_path() . '\test\test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    dd($output);
}
```

But it return me `null`.

The output should be `Hello World!`

---

### test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print('Hello World!')
```

---

If a create a php file outside my laravel folder with this

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('python C:\wamp64\www\projects\laravel\public\test\test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

And when I run `php path/outside/laravel/test.php` from the command line, I see the correct result.

---

The `test.py` have the right permission (`-rwxr-xr-x`). And python is also correct regarding the environnement path.

I also tried to use the full path of the script, but is still failing.

PS: The answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020068/running-python-script-in-laravel) are not working for me

Answer (score 0):

For first, maybe "php user" dont have permission for running? I meen php dont see global path variable.

Also, you can use library for it Symfony\Proccess