# Laravel - Python script execution

Tags: python, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have to execute a Python script which pulls a large amount of data to the database. It is working fine while I am running a project using the command `php artisan serve`, but it is throwing an error after calling the public folder URL  given below

```
localhost/project/public
```

Error:

> The command "python /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/projectname/beta/projectname/public/python/pubmed_abstract/pubmed_engine.py '{"term":"cancer"}'" failed.
>
> Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/infocytosis/beta/infocytosis/public Output:
>
> ================ Error Output: ================
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/projectname/beta/projectname/public/python/pubmed_abstract/pubmed_engine.py", line 5, in  from Bio import Entrez ImportError: No module named Bio

Code I used:

```
   $python_path=public_path().'/python/doom_abstract/doom_engine.py';
   
   $variables='{"term":"'.addslashes($request->term).'"}';

   $process = new Process("python $python_path '$variables'");
   $process->run(); 

  return redirect()->back()->withMessage('Filter saved successfully');
```

Comment: line 5, in _from Bio import Entrez ImportError: No module named Bio_ points at the problem. It looks like the python script contains errors or dependencies are missing. Maybe you need to switch to the correct python environment first?

Comment: That error won't appear and works fine if i run project with internal server like php artisan serve.It appears when the I call like http://localhost/laravel/infocytosis/beta/infocytosis/public/    @dbrumann

Comment: I think `php artisan serve` is using php-cli to run commands but when you use a web server (apache or nginx), there is no php-cli. try something more pure. like `exec` or `shel_exec` instead of `Process`

Comment: have you tried something like  $process = new Process(["python",$python_path, $variables]); looks like the process method takes an array https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html
also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020068/running-python-script-in-laravel

Comment: I'm not sure but I faced a similar problem and fixed it by changing the environment before executing the script

Answer (score 1):

You can try following one

```
$python_path=public_path('python/doom_abstract/doom_engine.py');
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
$process = new Process("python $python_path '$variables'");
$process->run();
```

how about

```
shell_exec("python $python_path '$variables'")
```