# Execute Python script using Laravel?

Tags: python-3.x, laravel, symfony

I'm trying to execute a python script in a Laravel 5.8 project but I'm having problems with the Symfony/process class.

Basically, I want to run this python script that takes an excel form from the storage folder.

**My first try was this**

```
$process = new Process('C:\Python\python.exe C:\Users\"my path"\laravel\storage\app\images\cargaExcel.py');

$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

**And the error is**

```
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
```

I also tried with `shell_exec()`, and if the two files (the excel and the python script are in the public path - app/public) it works.

**I think the problem is that python only executes on the app/public folder, so I don't know how to run this in another path.**

Python output is telling me that:

```
Working directory: C:\Users\"my path"\laravel\public
```

Does anyone know how to run this?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020068/running-python-script-in-laravel

Comment: how about `$cwd = getcwd(); chdir(new wordking direcotry); run python; chdir($cwd)` ?

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, that's the way to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running python script in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41020068/608639), [How to run Python Script in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38724318/608639), etc.

Comment: create a virtual environment venv of python & run that python file path in virtual env from instance of process class

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the working directory as the second argument of the process class

So it can be:

```
$process = new Process('C:\Python\python.exe C:\Users\"my path"\laravel\storage\app\images\cargaExcel.py', "/my/working/path/");
```

Also you may pass command as array

```
$process = new Process(['C:\Python\python.exe', 'C:\Users\"my path"\laravel\storage\app\images\cargaExcel.py'], "/my/working/path/");
```