# Run Python script from Laravel

Tags: php, python, linux, laravel, process

I am trying to build a system in Laravel from which I am able to call some python scripts. Starting with https://github.com/maurosoria/dirsearch, I have placed the python script with the same machine and tried to run on api call.

If I run `shall_exec('ls -la');` it runs perfectly and returns me result. 
But when I run the following command, the execution ends and no output.

```
shall_exec("python3 dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py -u https://www.yahoo.com/ -e *");
```

Then I used
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html and try the same steps

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process("python3 dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py -u https://www.yahoo.com/ -e *");
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

In this case also the `$process->run();` returns me no result.

Comment: The documentation of the Symfony Process component tells you, that you have to pass in the parameters of the command as an array:
`new Process(['python3', 'dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py', '-u', 'https://www.yahoo.com/', '-e', '*']);`
Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Can you please verify that the python file is exectuable and found by that relative path by running `shell_exec('ls -la dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py');`?

Comment: I ran ```shell_exec('ls -la dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py')``` works fine.

Then I tried ```new Process(['python3', 'dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py', '-u', 'https://www.yahoo.com/', '-e', '*']);``` I get following error ```ERR > /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied```

I change chmod to 777, still same error

Comment: I changed ownership of the Python code and I also changed a few lines of code, I get more detailed error:
```Symfony \ Component \ Process \ Exception \ ProcessFailedException
The command "'python3' 'dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py' '-u' 'https://www.yahoo.com/' '*'" failed. Exit Code: 2(Misuse of shell builtins) Working directory: ../public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running python script in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41020068/608639), [How to run Python Script in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38724318/608639), [Execute Python script using Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55183156/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Custom `Artisan` command if you want. Create a new Artisan Command by running `php artisan make:command COMMAND_NAME`. it will create a new Artisan command in `app\Console\Commands` directory of your project.

```
class Analytics extends Command{

    protected $signature = 'Run:Shell {path} {u} {e}';

    protected $description = 'Run Python Via Server Shell';

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle(){
        $output = shall_exec("python3 ".$this->argument('path')." -u ".$this->argument('u')." -e ".$this->argument('e'));
        $this->info($output);
    }
}
```

Now, you can run the artisan command as `php artisan Run:Shell path='dirsearch-master/dirsearch.py' u='https://www.yahoo.com/' e='*'` and the output will be printed to CMD. You can also run this Artisan command from any controller you want as,

```
// Taking Inputs from Request in Controller
Artisan::call("Run:Shell", ['path' => $request->input('path'), 'u' => $request->input('u') , 'e' => $request->input('e')]);
```

In fact, you can make the entire wrapper to run the python on your server-side using Laravel. But you should have the `python3` installed and configured on your server before running it.